# do not understand string matching

Tags: r, string, stringr

Trying to match strings, one is not matching that *should*

Can anyone explain this behaviour for me? Using `stringr` functions the match is not detected but when checking with `==` it is?

```
str_detect(str_sub(bit1, 1485, 1739), snips[10])
# [1] FALSE

str_sub(bit1, 1485, 1739) == snips[10]    
# [1] TRUE
```

When I look at `str_sub(bit1, 1485, 1739)` and `snips[10]` they look identical and are in fact from the same original source material.

Here is the actual block of text:

```
    str_detect("HANOI - China has shut trade ports to Vietnamese vessels as the bird flu crisis deepens, the Xinhua News Agency reported. Some 40 ports along a 740-mile (791 kilometers) border with Vietnam have been closed in the southern Chinese province of Yunnan, stat", "HANOI - China has shut trade ports to Vietnamese vessels as the bird flu crisis deepens, the Xinhua News Agency reported. Some 40 ports along a 740-mile (791 kilometers) border with Vietnam have been closed in the southern Chinese province of Yunnan, stat")
    [1] FALSE
```

Or even this result?

```
    str_detect(str1, str1)
    [1] FALSE
```

Comment: bit1 is a bigger block of text, snips[10] is a character vector extracted from a div from the same block.. both scraped using rvest from a website

Comment: Still not reproducible. We need to be able to type everything in to our R sessions so we can reproduce all the behavior, so need to know what bit1 and snips contain. Thanks :)

Comment: That is the full text - just a copy and paste. But I have isolated it it unescaped parenthesis causing the problem.

Comment: The parens in the second string are making it appear to be a pattern, not a literal string. Either escape them (`\\(` and `\\)`), use `==` or `identical`, or learn to use proper regexes in the pattern.